# tf2 conversion (bullet to geometry_msgs)

Tags: ros, bullet, tf2, geometry-msgs, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I wish to convert from Gazebo `math::Pose` type to one of the `geometry_msgs` ROS messages.

I can convert from `math::Pose` to  `btTransform` using [BulletTypes.hh](https://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/dev/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1BulletTypes.html).

I have tried with `tf2::convert()` method following the [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Migration/DataConversions#tf2), but it fails:

```
btTransform bt_T = physics::BulletTypes::ConvertPose(model_->GetLink("link")->GetWorldPose());
tf2::Stamped<btTransform> bt_T_stamped(bt_T, ros::Time::now(), "world");
geometry_msgs::TransformStamped T;
tf2::convert(bt_T_stamped, T);
```

I can obviously do this by hand, but is it there a way to use the `tf2::convert()` method properly?

**EDIT:** you can find the error log in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/alextoind/0888d89d704b964fd084).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229466/tf2-conversion-(bullet-to-geometry_msgs)/) by [alextoind](https://answers.ros.org/users/20595/alextoind/) on ROS Answers with karma: 217 on 2016-03-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-18**:
Why doesn't it work? What error message do you get?

**Comment by [alextoind](https://answers.ros.org/users/20595/alextoind/) on 2016-03-19**:
@ahendrix I have added the error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From your error message, it looks like the compiler can't find an implementation of the conversion from  btTransform to a message.

Are you including the tf2_bullet header that provides this conversion function? Try adding:

```
#include "tf2_bullet/tf2_bullet.h"
```

**UPDATE**

It looks like the conversion from a bullet transform to a TF2 transform hasn't been written yet; it isn't listed in the [tf2_bullet header](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf2_bullet/html/tf2__bullet_8h.html)

Similar to the [existing functions](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf2_bullet/html/tf2__bullet_8h_source.html), you could try writing the conversion yourself; it would probably look something like:

```
namespace tf2 {

inline
geometry_msgs::TransformStamped toMsg(const tf2::Stamped<btTransform>& in)
{
  geometry_msgs::TransformStamped msg;
  // TODO: actual conversion here
  return msg;
}

} // namespace tf2
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alextoind](https://answers.ros.org/users/20595/alextoind/) on 2016-03-21**:
@ahendrix I am really sorry that I had forgot to uncomment that include when I was creating the gist... Unfortunately that header is already included in my code, but it still does not compile. I have updated the gist with the correct error log. Thank you for your patience.

**Comment by [alextoind](https://answers.ros.org/users/20595/alextoind/) on 2016-03-21**:
Thank you very much @ahendrix! In your opinion, should I create a pull request in https://github.com/ros/geometry_experimental/ if everything works fine?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-21**:
Yes; if you come up with a conversion you like, you should submit it as a pull request.